# How to execute CURL API command from python

Tags: python-3.x, api, curl

Here is the CURL API I have and I want to execute through python but I'm getting error " FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'curl' " but I'm using OS library in python.

```
import os

os.system(curl -H "public-api-token: 2dd81854fca7bcbd657bd06a99a46l9s" -X PUT -d "dataMapsGoogle=google.com" https://api.googlemaps/v1/data/url')
```

How to execute the CURL command through python? I tried with os.system() but if there is any better answer then it would be helpful.

Comment: Why not using [Requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)?

Answer (score 0):

Use 'Subprocess' module:

```
import subprocess

cmd = ['curl', '-H', "public-api-token:....", ...]
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
```

Comment: I tried the subprocess but I got this error " ncurl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_CERT_EXPIRED (0x80090328) - The received certificate has expired " while execute through Terminal It's working.

Comment: try adding '--ssl-no-revoke' option to the command.